# RxJS 5 Observable: does any result belong to a known set

Tags: typescript, observable, rxjs5

I'm coding in `Typescript 1.9` and using `RxJS 5`. I'm trying to build an observable that will emit just one value: `true` if any of the inner `Observable<number>`'s emissions belong to a fixed array of numbers. `false` otherwise.  This is my code:

```
let lookFor = [2,7]; // Values to look for are known
Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]) //inner observable emits these dynamic values
    .first( //find first value to meet the requirement below
        (d:number) => lookFor.find(id=>id===d)!==undefined,
        ()=>true //projection function. What to emit when a match is found
    )
    .subscribe(
        res => console.log('Result: ',res),
        err => console.error(err),
        ()  => console.log('Complete')
    );
```

The code above works great. It will ouput:

> Result: true (because inner observable emits 2, which is found in `lookFor`
>
> Complete

If I start with `Observable.from([8,9])` I would like to get `Result: false` since there is no overlap with `lookFor`, but instead the error handler is triggered:

> Object {name:"Empty Error", stack:""}

What's the right approach to get my observable to emit `true` as soon as a match is found, but to emit `false` if there is still no match at the end of the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional parameter that lets you specify the default value to use if no match is found:

```
...
.first( //find first value to meet the requirement below
    (d:number) => lookFor.find(id=>id===d)!==undefined,
    ()=>true, //projection function. What to emit when a match is found
    false //default value to emit if no match is found
)
...
```